# MongoDB: Finding by nested key vs top-level key

Tags: performance, mongodb, schema

**Option 1:**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  text: String,
  author: {
    id: ObjectId,
    name: String,
    email: String
  }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  text: String,
  authorId: Id,
  author: {
    name: String,
    email: String
  }
}
```

I have a schema for Post documents similar to option 1 above.  There is a separate 'Author' collection, which the author ID fields above are referencing.  The 'name' and 'email' have been duplicated here; there is more author information on the Author collection.

One of my queries on the Post collection will be querying for all posts by a certain author ID.

In terms of performance, is it best to go with Option 2 because the author ID key is at the 'top-level' of the document?  Is there any difference if you search for documents by a nested key like in Option 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it won't make a significant performance difference. MongoDb can very well index a 'top-level' key or 'nested key'.
MongoDb can internally read full BSON object, hence reach any part of it efficiently.
Read here :
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON

You can try creating a 2 test collections, and create indexes on the queried fields.
The performance will be the same.